# SQL Server 2008 R2 Snapshot isolation issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, snapshot-isolation

I'm using SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT with snapshot enabled on the database but what I'm noticing is that if I do a simple delete statement such as

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DELETE * FROM TableA
INSERT INTO TableA(...) SELECT (...) FROM TableB
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Effectively wiping out the table clean and re-populating it with new data as data is loaded in from another table. Whilst this operation is happening, doing a simple select which also runs in a transaction with snapshot declared, for example

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT

SELECT ID FROM TableA WHERE SomeColumn = 'A'
```

Does a scan on the table if the DELETE / INSERT statements are running otherwise an index seek. Is that expected behaviour?

Comment: Some further investigation, it looks like the statistics of the db are lost when this is running. Still no resolution though :(